# What happens with an event if the consuming client is down in NServicebus?

Tags: nservicebus

Let say you have two system A and B. System B is set up to listen to event from system A. Due to some weird problem system B is down for a serious amount of time. What will happen with the events produced by system A during that period? Will B get them B is up and running again? Is there some timeout or so? What happens if you decide to actually delete B, how do you tell A that B does no longer exist?

Answer (score 2):

> What will happen with the events produced by system A during that
>   period? Will B get them (when) B is up and running again?

Yes.  The messages are durable, so they are queued up in the infrastructure (MSMQ, SQL Server, or whatever you are using) to be delivered when the subscriber is back online.

> Is there some timeout or so?

Unless you specify a timeout using the `TimeToBeReceivedAttribute`, there would be no time out in this situation.  There may be a practical limit on how many messages can be queued up, but no time constraints that I know of.

> What happens if you decide to actually delete B, how do you tell A
>   that B does no longer exist?

B would have to explicitly unsubscribe, or you would have to manually remove the subscription information from the infrastructure (RavenDB or the database if you are using NHibernate).  There may be additional tooling that allows you to do this via their 4.x platform.